# Error with the address of a char in c

Tags: c, pointers, char

I am having some problems with this situation. I want to iterate through the ASCII table and save those values into a char*. My code is like this:

```
for(char c = '.'; c <= 'z'; c++)
{
    char* key = c; //I would like to get key = "A", key = "B" and so on
}
```

I try:

```
for(char c = '.'; c <= 'z'; c++)
{
    char* key = &c; 
}
```

But then if I print "key" using printf, I get strange values and not "A", "B", etc. I get values like f@�F�50

Comment: .... If your problem is with the printing code, why didn't you show it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A C string should always be zero-byte terminated. So try:

```
for(char c = '.'; c <= 'z'; c++) {
  char buf[2];
  buf[0] = c;
  buf[1] = '\0';
  printf("buf=%s\n", buf);
}
```

The address of `c` is followed by garbage bytes (probably non-zero). So printing `&c` (as a C string) is [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use these as characters then this works,

```
main()
{
    char c;
    char *key;
  for(c = '.'; c <= 'z'; c++)
{
 key = &c; 
  printf("%c\n",*key);
}
}
```

use key as a character pointer so use dereferencing to get character.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `%c` conversion specifier in the format string of `printf` to print a character.

```
for(char c = '.'; c <= 'z'; c++)
{
    char *key = &c;
    printf("%c\n", *key); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(char c = '.'; c <= 'z'; c++)
{
    char* key = &c; //I would like to get key = "A", key = "B" and so on
    printf("%c ", *key);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can simple pass int value as param to printf();

I wrote a util to print ascii chars, take a look:

```
#include  <stdio.h>

extern void printAsciiPartly(int start, int end);

int main() {
    int charCount = 26;
    int numCount = 10;
    int allCount = (1<<7);

    int upperStart = 65;
    int upperEnd = upperStart + charCount - 1;

    int lowerStart = 97;
    int lowerEnd = lowerStart + charCount - 1;

    int numStart = 48;
    int numEnd = numStart + numCount - 1;

    int allStart = 0;
    int allEnd = allStart + allCount - 1;

    printAsciiPartly(upperStart, upperEnd);
    printAsciiPartly(lowerStart, lowerEnd);
    printAsciiPartly(numStart, numEnd);
    // printAsciiPartly(allStart, allEnd);
}

void printAsciiPartly(int start, int end) {
    int i;
    int counter = 0;
    int countOfEachLine = 10;

    printf("------ ascii char: [%d] ~ [%d] ------\n",start, end);
    for(i=start; i<=end; i++) {
        counter++;
        counter%=countOfEachLine;
        printf("[%d]%c, ",i, i);
        if(counter==0) {
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
    printf("\n\n");
}
```